# Chartjs line chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two charts in my application right now that both use chartjs. One is a bar chart, which works perfectly. The second, doesn't render at all and I'm not sure why. I created the second in a dummy html page and copied the code over, but when I put it in my real application, it breaks.

I have this html:

```
<div class="card text-white">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="display-4" id="graphTitle"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
         <canvas id="myLineChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="1DBTN">1D</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="1mBTN">1M</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="3mBTN">3M</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="6mBTN">6M</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="ytdBTN">YTD</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="1YBTN">1Y</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="2YBTN">2Y</button>
               <button class="btn btn-success" name="graphBTN" id="5YBTN">5Y</button>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

As for the javascript,

I have the following global variables.

```
// graphing global variables
    var ctx;
    var myBarChart;
    var myLineChart;
```

I have a function to generate a line chart (this is static test data):

```
function createLineChart() {

        // Our labels along the x-axis
        var years = [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050];
        // For drawing the lines
        var africa = [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478];
        var asia = [282,350,411,502,635,809,947,1402,3700,5267];
        var europe = [168,170,178,190,203,276,408,547,675,734];
        var latinAmerica = [40,20,10,16,24,38,74,167,508,784];
        var northAmerica = [6,3,2,2,7,26,82,172,312,433];

        ctx = $('#myLineChart');
        myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: years,
            datasets: [
                { 
                    data: africa
                }
            ]
        }
        });
}
```

Then, inside a button click, I call about 8 functions, one of them being this one.

```
createLineChart();
```

All of the functions work on the button click (see picture), but the graph. I get no errors. All console logs appear to be normal. It just doesn't show up like my other (bar chart) graphs do - which are using dynamic data sets.

[image]

Comment: If you inspect the source after clicking the button, does the `myLineChart` canvas element have content generated/added to it? Or is it still empty? Trying to work out if it's a display/css issue, or Chartjs is failing.

Comment: no content is being added to the html...

Comment: You mentioned that you tried the same function/creation in a dummy page and it works fine. So this is really hard to troubleshoot without the entire HTML document. I suspect you might have a targeting issue (another function is overwriting the content of this element or what you've put here isn't exactly what's in your file)